# Continuity of implicitly defined function

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Consider a function $g(x)$ defined implicitly via

$$\int_x^{x + g(x)} f(\xi) \,d \xi - u(x) = 0. $$

I know that for every $x$ a unique $g(x)$ exists.
Furthermore $f$ is locally integrable and $u$ is some continuous function.

Will $g$ be continuous and how could I prove this?

Comment: Is $f$ strictly positive, or at least is the primitive function of $f$ strictly increasing? Is $u$ increasing?

Comment: Write $F(x,y) = \int^{x+y}_x f(\xi)d\xi -u(x)$, then $\partial_y F(x,y) = f(x+y)$. Now use the implicit function theorem. Check its applicability.

Comment: It is my understanding that for applying the implicit function theorem, $F$ would need to be continuously differentiable which it not necessarily is. For example, $u$ could be piecewise linear.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I know that $f$ is strictly positive on \mathbb R. Sorry, forgot to mention that. $u$ is just continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a primitive function of $f$, that is, $F(x) = \int_0^x f(y) dy$. If $f$ is positive a.e., then the inverse function $F^{-1}(x)$ is well-defined, and it is continuous. (Interestingly, it is in fact absolutely continuous, with $(F^{-1})'(x) = 1/f(F^{-1}(x))$ for a.e. $x$; however, this is no longer true if $f$ is nonnegative, even if we assume that $F$ is strictly increasing; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544618/is-the-inverse-of-a-absolutely-continuous-function-with-almost-everywhere-positi)).

The equation we are to solve is $$F(x+g(x)) - F(x) = u(x).$$ Equivalently, $$g(x) = F^{-1}(F(x) + u(x)) - x .$$ The right-hand side is clearly continuous and unique, as long as $F(x) + u(x)$ is in the range of $F$.